# Unity asking NDK version that is no longer available

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-ndk

The version of NDK Unity asking me to install is not on google site [NDK Versions](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases#ndk-19c-downloads). The only one available is **r19 version 19.2.5345600** but unity app is asking for **r19 version 19.0.52321**"
[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb0CV.png)

Yeah, I know the problem can be solved by using Unity Hub but the reason I am not using that is because Unity Hub takes forever to download anything and my connection is slow. Unity Hub times out a lot and I have to install the entire unity 3D software and all of the external tools using it in order to download the NDK using Unity Hub. Currently, Unity doesn't allow you to add modules if Unity 3D is not downloaded using Unity Hub.

I have tried installing NDK r18 and r20 but that doesn't work, same problem.

So can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try spoofing your NDK version, though this may cause unexpected behaviour. In Android `ndk-r19c`, modify `source.properties` such that:

```
Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
Pkg.Revision = 19.0.5232133
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Android Studio installed, (or can access via **sdk manager**, I guess )You can download the ndk version requested by Unity (r19 - 19.0.5232133) using the SDK manager.

**Note**: you have to uncheck the **hide obsolete packages** option

[image: sdk manager]